# type 'list<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'string' flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to code in Flutter and right now I'm trying to get data from restapi. I'm getting this error type `'list<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'string'`  and in debug

[image: Screenshoot of debug error]

Any solution?

apiservice:

```
Future<List<Petani>> getDafPet() async {
final response = await client.get("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/dafPetani");
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return petaniFromJson(response.body);
} else {
  return null;
}
```

}

dart:

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: ApiServices().getDafPet(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Petani>> snapshot){
              if(snapshot.hasError){
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Something wrong with message : ${snapshot.error.toString()}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFAB47BC),
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                );
              }else if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                lptn = snapshot.data;
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, position){
                    return Card(
                      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 5.0),
                      shadowColor: Color(0xFFBA68C8),
                      elevation: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 2.5, 5, 2.5),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5),
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            //lDsn[position].nik
                            lptn[position].nama,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFFAB47BC),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            lptn[position].nama,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              fontSize: 13,
                            ),
                          ),
                          trailing: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                              color: Colors.black26,
                              size: 20,
                            ),
                            onPressed: (){
                              //pindah ke menu Daftar Jadwal Dosen
                              // Navigator.push(
                              //   context,
                              //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DaftarJadwalDosen(title: "Daftar Slot Jadwal Dosen",
                              //     nik: lDsn[position].nik, dsn: lDsn[position], nim_login: this.nim_login,)),).then(onGoBack);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: lptn.length,
                );
              }
```

JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "ID_User": "00",
        "nama": "Test Ganti",
        "jenis_kelamin": 0,
        "tanggal_lahir": "0000-00-00",
        "alamat": "",
        "provinsi": "",
        "kabupaten": "",
        "kecamatan": "",
        "kelurahan_desa": "",
        "nomor_telpon": "14022",
        "Email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "Foto": ""
    },
    {
        "ID_User": "000",
        "nama": "Test Jawaban",
        "jenis_kelamin": 0,
        "tanggal_lahir": "0000-00-00",
        "alamat": "",
        "provinsi": "",
        "kabupaten": "",
        "kecamatan": "",
        "kelurahan_desa": "",
        "nomor_telpon": "080989999",
        "Email": "a@jawab.id",
        "Foto": ""
    },
    {
        "ID_User": "003",
        "nama": "test Jawaban 3",
        "jenis_kelamin": 0,
        "tanggal_lahir": "0000-00-00",
        "alamat": "",
        "provinsi": "",
        "kabupaten": "",
        "kecamatan": "",
        "kelurahan_desa": "",
        "nomor_telpon": "1234",
        "Email": "c@c.id",
        "Foto": ""
    },
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: just edited the post

Comment: can you decode your response data

Comment: can you add petaniFromJson() function?

Comment: List<Petani> petaniFromJson(String jsonData) {
  final data = json.decode(jsonData);
  print("Data = " + data);
  return List<Petani>.from(data.map((item) => Petani.fromJson(item)));
}

Comment: In your Text widget: lptn[position].nama.toString(); and put int before position when passing it in list view.

Comment: can u put an example? where to put the int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this

```
Future<List<Petani>> getDafPet() async {
final response = await client.get("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/dafPetani");
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = json.decode(response.body);
  List<Petani> itemList = [];
        data.map(( item) {
              itemList.add(Petani.fromJson(item));
         }).toList();
   return itemList;
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: still same as before

Comment: class Petani {
  String id;
  String password;
  String nama;
  int jenis_kelamin;
  String tanggal_lahir;
  String alamat;
  String provinsi;
  String nomor_telpon;
  String email;
  String jum_pekerja;
  String jum_lahan;

Comment: updated my answer please have a look and it works in my machine

Comment: it still returning type 'list<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'string' flutter

Comment: edited my answer please try it

Comment: you are welcome, Happy coding!